# Triac and Optoisolator not turning on lightbulb

Tags: microcontroller, triac

I'm trying to switch on a lamp using a microcontroller. I've wired the schematic below using a 5v power supply instead of the microcontroller for now and the first time I turned on the lamp   the light bulb flashed quickly and would not come back on or flash again. Note: I am using an MOC3010 instead of a MOC3081.

[image]

This is based off a schematic below I found online that was said to be for switching on a lightbulb

[image]

Did I miss something completely? Why isn't mine working correctly?

Comment: What kind of bulb? Does the symptom repeat or will it not turn on at all now? What voltage are you using? (I assume it's AC?)

Comment: Just a normal 70 watt bulb. It will not turn on at all now. Using standard wall outlet voltage 120VAC. I also made sure the bulb didn't burn out, it still works.

Comment: If it won't turn on at all now then it suggests something is blown or become disconnected - if not the bulb, then the MOC3010 or the triac (do you have spares?). Try the lower value resistor just to make sure it will definitely trigger as Connor mentions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure whatever is driving the MOC3010 can sink 15 mA? The MOC3010 is only guaranteed to switch at 15 mA forward current through the LED. The optriac may switch at lower forward currents, but the apparently Motorola bins those parts by forward current sensitivity, and the 3010 is the lowest sensitivity.

[image]

> <sub>IFT = LED Trigger Current, Current Required to Latch Output</sub>

With a footnote:

> All devices are guaranteed to trigger at an I<sub>F</sub> value less than or equal
>   to max I<sub>FT</sub>. Therefore, recommended operating IFlies between max
>   3.IFT(15 mA for MOC3010, 10 mA for MOC3011, 5 mA for MOC3012) and absolute max I<sub>F</sub>(60 mA).

What is driving the LED? Can you measure the voltage on the IO line going to the optocoupler?

It's also worth noting that even with the microcontroller completely out of the picture, you'll only get 10 mA forward current with a 330Ω resistor (\$5V - 1.5V_{F} = 3.5V\$ across the resistor. \$\frac{3.5V}{330} = ~10.6 mA\$).

Comment: I'm using 4 AAs and a LDO to bring it down to 5V for the optocoupler LED. I measured it and its getting 5V and should have no problem getting 15mA

Comment: @user2665581 - see edits. One, your MCU may not be able to sink 15 mA. Two - you cannot get 15 mA with a 330Ω resistor anyways.